# Keep x most common observations within a variable?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
> dput(dt)
structure(list(ID = 1:10, City = c("New York", "New York", "LA", 
"LA", "LA", "Boston", "Chicago ", "New York", "LA", "New York"
), Random_Info_To_Keep = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I would only like to keep the data if the row contains the 2 most common cities in the dataset (New York/LA). The output should look like this:

```
> dput(dt2)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 10L), City = c("New York", 
"New York", "LA", "LA", "LA", "New York", "LA", "New York"), 
    Random_Info_To_Keep = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 2):

base R:

```
dt[dt$City %in% names(sort(table(dt$City), decreasing = TRUE)[1:2]), ]

# version by @M-- using tail
dt[ dt$City %in% names( tail( table( dt$City) , 2) ) , ]

 ID     City Random_Info_To_Keep
1   1 New York                   1
2   2 New York                   1
3   3       LA                   1
4   4       LA                   1
5   5       LA                   1
8   8 New York                   1
9   9       LA                   1
10 10 New York                   1
```

Comment: ```dt[ dt$City %in% names( tail( table( dt$City) , 2) ) , ]``` I think using `tail` is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can first count how many times each city is present in the dataset and then filter the two with most occurences in the data. Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  add_count(City, name = "helper_count") %>% # adding the frequency with which each city occurs
  slice_max(order_by = helper_count, n = 2) %>% # two most common
  select(-helper_count)
```

Comment: You can reduce the first three dplyr lines to one by simply using `add_count(City)` instead of `group_by(...) %>% mutate(...) %>% ungroup(...)`

Comment: jpsmith thanks. Edited my answer to include your suggestion.